# Automata and Formal Languages: Are there also non-regular grammars for regular languages?

Tags: computer-science, automata

In Automata and Formal Languages, are there also grammars that are not right-/left-linear but still produce a regular language?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following non-regular grammar generates the regular language $01^*01^*01^*$; however, it could be transformed into a regular grammar.

$S \to 0A0A0A$ 
$A \to 1A|\varepsilon$